# Data extraction from Salesforce to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, etl

**My requirement:** 
I have to pull complete data i.e., all the objects/fields from Salesforce to my Amazon S3 Bucket for data further data analysis on Historical data. We are highly relying on open source ways to accomplish.

**What have I tried?**

1. Via Amazon Glue job: Currently, I have done this activity for some Salesforce objects like Opportunity, Leads, Accounts, Contacts via using AWS Glue, where I have written multiple Glue jobs in Scala to connect to Salesforce and pull the data in Spark Dataframes and dump it in the S3 bucket.

2.Using this reference, I have tried to pull the Salesforce objects in to S3. Please ignore activities involved post Amazon S3 in this 
[URL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/extracting-salesforce-com-data-using-aws-glue-and-analyzing-with-amazon-athena/)

3.Data Virtuality Pipe(3rd party connector).: This is helpful in fetching as many objects we need. There is a limitation on to where the data dumping targets.

4.Tried few other connectors like Heroku.

**Challenges:**

1.Pulling data even for few objects takes longer

2. We need to create multiple glue jobs (approx. there are 100+ Salesforce objects we are considering to pull)

3.Data transformation (i.e., data type conversion, cleanup) is huge as Glue job is not maintaining data type integrity while pulling data from Salesforce.

4.Huge maintenance involved to take care of the jobs.

5.Through third party connectors, huge cost is involved.

Comment: I am using Data Virtuality and could not understand the limitation about Data Virtuality Pipes. Actually on DV Studio we can easily create a replication job to store the data on an other data source or analytical storage of the DV server

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Spark along with Salesforce integration to process the salesforce objects or perform ETL operation on them. Have a look at below code:-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import com.springml.spark.salesforce
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import com.sforce.async
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject
import com.springml.salesforce.wave.api.{ ForceAPI, WaveAPI }
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.List
import java.io.{ BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter }
import org.apache.http.impl.client.{ DefaultHttpClient, BasicResponseHandler }
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.postgresql.Driver

object SparkSalesForceReaderWriter {

  def SparkSForceIntegration(Spark: SparkSession) = {

    val sc = Spark.sparkContext
    val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

    val userName = "username"
    val password = "password"

    val config = new ConnectorConfig()
    config.setUsername(userName)
    config.setPassword(password)
    val authEndpoint = ("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/46.00") // https:login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/46.00
    config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndpoint)
    config.setServiceEndpoint(authEndpoint);
    val conn = new PartnerConnection(config);
    var connection = conn.describeGlobal()
    val sobjectResults = connection.getSobjects()
    var res = conn.describeSObject(" salesforce object name")
    var fields = res.getFields().toBuffer;
    println("Has " + fields.length + " fields");
    var strFields = ""

    fields.foreach { x =>
      if (x == null || x == "" || x == " ") {
        strFields = x.getName;
      } else {
        strFields = strFields + "," + x.getName;
      }
    }

    var qry = "select " + strFields.toString.replaceFirst(",", "") + " from Account"
    println("Your query is ==========>>>> " + qry)

    val salesForceDataReader = Spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
      .option("username", userName)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("soql", qry)
      .option("version", "46.0")
      .load()

  }

}
```

Once the data is successfully read into spark dataframe , this is how to write out to s3 in scala/spark2 on s3n.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "[access key]")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "[secret key]")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")

salesForceDataReader.write
.mode("overwrite")
.parquet("s3n://bucket/folder/parquet/myFile")
```

This is how to do it with s3a, which is preferred.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "[access key]")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "[secret key]")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

salesForceDataReader.write
.mode("overwrite")
.parquet("s3a://bucket/folder/parquet/myFile")
```

With the above approach you can use spark speed and performance and can perform your ETL job faster. You can even write the salesforce object data into SQL tables as well as Files.

Comment: Hi Bipin, Currently I am following the same method using Amazon Glue jobs. As internally glue jobs runs over Spark cluster .